# Haskell: typeclass and instance (Not in scope: data constructor..)

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I want to make a typeclass Size with a method that given a value computes the number of
constructors in this value.

```
class Size a where
  size :: a -> Int

instance Size Int where
  size a = 1

instance Size Bool where
  size b = 1

instance Size (c,d) where
  size (c,d) = 1 + Size c + Size d

example4 :: (Bool,(Int,Bool))
example4 = (True,(3,False))
```

```
main :: IO ()    
main = do
  print (size example4)
```

It should give me the value 5 but 
I get the error Message `` Not in scope: data constructor `Size' ``.

I want to use `Size Int` or `Size Bool` in the `Size(c,d)` instance, but have no idea how.

My Problem is that I don't know how I can fix it, because I'm fairly new to Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
size (c,d) = 1 + size c + size d
```

Note `Size` is thought as a data constructor since it has capital S. What you need is the function `size`.

Also, `c` and `d` also need to be types that are in the `Size` class, or `size` cannot be called on them

```
instance (Size c, Size d) => Size (c,d) where
```

So to complete it would be:

```
instance (Size c, Size d) => Size (c,d) where
  size (c,d) = 1 + size c + size d
```

Comment: Thank you it works correct now and i worked 2 hours on it -.-